# x-flipox not working on custom polymer element

Tags: polymer, x-tag

Hi all I am trying to create a custom Polymer Element that uses the < x-flipbox > element inside its template tag.

However it seems that the < x-flipbox > tag it is only working on the index page and not inside my custom elements.

This is my custom element, what am I doing wrong?

```
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">

<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/x-tag-imports/x-tag-flipbox.html">

<polymer-element name="nautes-flipbox" attributes="">
  <template>
    <style>
      :host {
        display: block;
      }
    </style>


  <x-flipbox>
      <div>I'm the front face.</div>
      <div>I'm the back face.</div>
  </x-flipbox>

  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer({

    });
  </script>
</polymer-element>
```

The element above is just showing the two divs.

```
<x-flipbox>
      <div>I'm the front face.</div>
      <div>I'm the back face.</div>
</x-flipbox>
```

This one pasted in the index.html shows only one div (as it should).

In addition, how can I debug this kind of issues? (I am new to polymer and the console is not giving me any error/warning)

Comment: What is x-tag-imports?  I can't find it on Bower.

Comment: I was used on one of the tutorial video on the polimer website (http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=75EuHl6CSTo&list=PLRAVCSU_HVYu-zlRaqArF8Ytwz1jlMOIM&index=10), here it is the github project link:https://github.com/x-tag/x-tag-imports

Comment: Does the xtag js object exist in global scope?  Open console, type xtag

Comment: Also, did bower bring in all dependencies?  x-tag-core, x-tag-flipbox, etc?

Comment: This is what I get on the console: http://i62.tinypic.com/2r5f13q.png

Comment: I have installed x-tag-core and x-tag-flipbox with bower, then moved the x-tag-imports folder inside my project. This is part of my directory tree: http://i59.tinypic.com/10pr3ah.png

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to include it as a import, that's an old wrapper thing the Polymer folks wrote for including X-Tag elements (it's probably what's complicating this). You can simply include the JS (as a `<script>`) and CSS (as a `<link rel="stylesheet">`) inside of the x-flipbox repo's `src` directory where you have your `<link rel="import">` for the flipbox

Repo: https://github.com/x-tag/flipbox/tree/master/src